# One of two Textboxes in Page Footer does not repeat when page breaks

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is a standard 8.5x11in and will be rendered as a PDF when ran. There will be occasions when the content in the page will spill over to a second or third page which is fine. However, there are two textboxes inside of the footer, one that displays the page number and one that shows the copyright value. When there is a second page the page number will be shown on the first page, but the copyright value will not be shown.

Here is the .rdl showing the footer section:

```
<PageFooter>
  <Height>0.28in</Height>
  <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
  <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
  <ReportItems>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle14">
      <ReportItems>
        <Textbox Name="Copyright">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>=ReportItems!Copyright1.Value</Value>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style>
                <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
              </Style>
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>Copyright</rd:DefaultName>
          <Left>0.43268in</Left>
          <Height>0.25in</Height>
          <Width>4.85687in</Width>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
        <Textbox Name="textbox42">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>="Page " + CStr(Globals!PageNumber) + " of " + CStr(Globals!TotalPages)</Value>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style>
                <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
              </Style>
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <Left>5.79167in</Left>
          <Height>0.25in</Height>
          <Width>1.375in</Width>
          <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
          <Style>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
      </ReportItems>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
      <Top>0.01in</Top>
      <Left>0.25in</Left>
      <Height>0.25in</Height>
      <Width>7.16667in</Width>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </Rectangle>
  </ReportItems>
  <Style>
    <Border>
      <Style>None</Style>
    </Border>
    <BackgroundColor>White</BackgroundColor>
  </Style>
</PageFooter>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, since everything I've found on SO or on MSDN/Google has primarily revolved around how to hide a footer or show it on all pages, but nothing involving this particular issue.

**EDIT:** This issue does not appear when the report is rendered as a word document, but unfortunately our clients who deal with this particular report require a PDF file.

**EDIT #2:** I also tried enclosing both textboxes within a rectangle in the footer with the `<KeepTogether></KeepTogether>` property set to true, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what my issue was. When the report was built, the value in the footer was referencing the value of an invisible textbox in the body of the report, which contained the value I need to display on the footer.

By changing the value of the textbox in the footer to reference the data field instead of a report item I was able to get it to show up on multiple pages. So the issue was:

```
<Value>=ReportItems!Copyright1.Value</Value>
```

when I needed:

```
<Value>=Fields!Copyright.Value</Value>
```